# mock $httpBackend regex not matched

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to match an url with a regex. But the follwing regex doesn't match.

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/^rest\/find-reservations\?.*/)').respond(function () {
        return [200, ['succes'], {}];
    });
```

I keep getting the follwing error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET rest/find-reservations?end=1421424299193&reservationClass=Reservation&start=1358352299193
No more request expected
```

When I change the regex to an absolute string '/find-reservations' the whenGET is triggered. Why is this?

edit:
I'm mocking a backend. http://plnkr.co/edit/VF4KbZO3FvngWQsiUcte?p=preview
The following plnkr works fine for static urls and partials. But it does not in the above case.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to match this url:

**"rest/find-reservations?end=1421424299193&reservationClass=Reservation&start=1358352299193"**

use this code:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^rest\/find-reservations\?.*/).respond(function () {
  return [200, ['success'], {}];
});
```

#### If you see this error `Error: Unexpected request:`

It can be for some reasons:

- You forget `$httpBackend.expectGET(url)`.
- The order of `expectGET` should be the same as the order of the `requests`.
- You called `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` before `$httpBackend.flush()`.

It is not related to `$httpBackend.whenGET` at all.

From the [$httpBackend docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend):

> Request expectations provide a way to make assertions about requests made by the application and to define responses for those requests. **The test will fail if the expected requests are not made or they are made in the wrong order**

Comment: Unexpected request: GET rest/find-reservations?end=1421424968745&reservationClass=Reservation&start=0

Comment: I temporarily hardcoded start and end for it to be easier to catch

Comment: I tested it on my machine, you forgot `$httpBackend.expectGET`

Comment: But I have several static whenGET's who all work. E.g.  $httpBackend.whenGET('rest/vn-slas').respond(function () {
  return [200, vnSlas, {}];
 });

Comment: The expectations should be in the same order as the requests!

Comment: @llan Frumer: The order of the request doesn't matter. I'll update the beginpost later with some more code

Answer (score 9):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Enclosing an expression in `'...'` makes it a string (even if it looks like a regular expression.
2. You must include the leading `/` in your pattern.

---

Your code should be modified like this:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/rest\/find-reservations\?.*/).respond(function () {
    return [200, 'success', {}];
});
```

Comment: This error is obviously related to some other part of your code, so please post more code or create an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** or prepare a fiddle to dmonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Vincent: What is this plunkr supposed to do ? I don't see anything reproducing your problem...

Comment: It mocks a backend and catches all requests which are being sent to the backend. As you and @Ilan Frumer mentioned, it was a regex problem. I forgot to remove the quotes from the regex and caught all uncaught urls with regex /.*/

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.httpBackend.whenGET(new RegExp('.*')).respond(function(){ return [200, 'MISS', {}] });
 this.httpBackend.whenPOST('/report/').respond(function(){return [200, 'HIT', {}] ; });
 this.httpBackend.whenPOST(new RegExp('.*')).respond(function(){ return      [200, 'MISS', {}] });

var _received;

var result = this.reportService.save(new this.Report());
result.then(function(response){
    _received = response.data;
});          
this.httpBackend.flush();
expect(_received).toBe('HIT');
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use Regex with 'data' property ? i would like to match the data of the request not the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question but in my case the issue was the fact the regex was created with the /g global flag and I'd like to share my answer in case someone else stumbles upon it for the same reason I did.

Although this doesn't answer the question, I hope it's usefull for someone nonetheless:

**Short version:**

Don't use /g global flags in combination with httpBackend url matching.

**TL;DR:**

Asuming you have a service called SomeService with a function called someFunction that executes a GET request, consider the following tests that demonstrate the impact of the global flag on the regex.

```
describe('Regex demo', function() {
    afterEach(function() {
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
    describe('Normal regex used once', function() {
        var url = new RegExp(baseUrl);
        it('first test', function() {
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, {});
            someService.someFunction();
        });
    });
    describe('Normal regex used multiple times', function() {
        var url = new RegExp(baseUrl);
        it('first test', function() {
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, {});
            someService.someFunction();
        });
        it('second test, no problem', function() {
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, {});
            someService.someFunction();
        });
    });
    describe('Regex with GLOBAL flag', function() {
        var url = new RegExp(baseUrl, 'g');
        it('first test', function() {
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, {});
            someService.someFunction();
        });
        it('second test with global, this will not pass!', function() {
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, {});
            someService.someFunction();
        });
    });
    describe('Regex with GLOBAL flag in before each', function() {
        var url;
        beforeEach(function() {
            url = new RegExp(baseUrl, 'g');
        });
        it('first test', function() {
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, {});
            someService.someFunction();
        });
        it('second test, passes although regex is global, it was renewed in     the before each', function() {
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, {});
            someService.someFunction();
        });
    });
});
```

Here are the corresponding test results:
[image]