# $httpBacked, Error: Unsatisfied requests for regexed when statement

Tags: angularjs, regex, unit-testing, httpbackend

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3481';
```

before each test I adding handler for that `GET` request

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', new RegExp(baseUrl + '/reports\\?.*', 'g'))
```

in one of `it` expression, I'm expecting the following request

```
var startTime = moment().subtract(1, 'week'),
    endTime = moment(),
    queryParams = "endTime=" + endTime.toISOString() + 
"&startTime=" + startTime.toISOString();

  $httpBackend.expectGET(baseUrl + '/reports?' + queryParams);
```

But I continue to get 
`Error: Unsatisfied requests [GET] http://localhost:3481/reports?endTime...`

I have tried regexp with that string and `reg.test()` method returns `true`
http://grab.by/NFHi

tried also with that

`'http://localhost:3481/reports?endTime=2016-01-27T20:41:52.302Z&startTime=2016-01-26T20:41:52.302Z'.match(new RegExp('http://localhost:3481' + '/reports\\?.*', 'g'))`
and it returns 
`["http://localhost:3481/reports?end..."]`

What is the problem here?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21169238/2435473) would help you

Comment: @PankajParkar I got another error
`Error: Unsatisfied requests` vs `Error: Unexpected request:`